# Inheritance and Linq-to-Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following models:

```
public class Person 
{
    long Id;
    string name;
}

public class Student : Person
{
    string studentId;
}

public class Bus
{
    long Id;

    public ICollection<Person> riders {set; get;}
}

public class SchoolBus : Bus
{
    long schoolBusNumber;
}
```

I also have the following code:

```
SchoolBus schoolBus = new SchoolBus();

schoolBus.riders = new List<Person>
{
    new Student { name = "Jim" },
    new Student { name = "Jane }
}


var query = from rider in SchoolBus.riders
    select new 
    {
        (rider as Student).studentId;
    }
```

Students and Person are set up as separate tables and I'm using DbContext.

I know why this would not work, but what are possible solutions for me to get this to return the right studentId by using a Person collection?

Comment: Turns out Lazy-Loading got me. Needed to use Include() to include the property that I need to load on the select.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var studentIds = rider.OfType<Student>().Select(x => x.studentId);
```

Comment: OfType is supported in Linq to Entities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738551.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly what you shown, this will work:

SchoolBus schoolBus = new SchoolBus();

```
schoolBus.riders = new List<Person>
{
    new Student { name = "Jim" },
    new Student { name = "Jane }
}
var query = from rider in SchoolBus.riders
select new 
{
    riderID = (rider as Student).studentId;
}
```

But if your query runs on linq2entity, you should show your exact code, and your problem.